# Как узнать, есть ли в базе MySQL запись?

Tags: php

Делаю выборку

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT time FROM LeadsTable WHERE phone = $phone LIMIT 1");
```

Как определить, есть ли нужная запись в базе?

Comment: `if ($result)`  значит вернул то, что просили

Comment: Я такой вариант сразу использовал, но почему-то он не работает. Поэтому подумал, что нужно как-то по другому.

Comment: У меня всегда true

Comment: Тут нужно смотреть, что вы имеете под словом `не работает`..... и конечно код вкупе, не оторванным от......

Comment: Это как-раз весь код :-) Выше только подключение к базе.

Comment: ну...и? тогда не ясно...... если true - значит выбрал. что тогда не работает?

Comment: В переменной $phone указан телефон, которого в базе нет. Но все-равно true.

Comment: Возможно есть другие варианты определения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `$mysqli` - это объект нативного класса `mysqli`, то метод `query` для `select` запроса будет возвращать всегда объект результата, если запрос был выполнен без ошибок. Ни одной строки не найдено - это частный случай успешного выполнения. А приведение объекта к булевому типу - всегда `true`. Поэтому `if ($result)`, разумеется, будет говорить только о том, что запрос был выполнен.

Вам нужно проверить или количество строк в результате:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

Или вызвать любой из методов `fetch_` для получения строки результата. Если `fetch` скажет `NULL`, значит ни одной строки найдено не было.

---

Обратите внимание на возможную SQL-инъекцию. Вообще никогда не подставляйте данные в текст запроса и используйте `prepared statements`. Тогда не придётся волноваться об этом вопросе, а использование переменной в тексте запроса должно вызывать чувство тревоги и желание проверить, что это за переменная и должна ли она вставляться как есть.